# pika, stop_consuming does not work

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm new to rabbitmq and pika, and is having trouble with stopping consuming.

channel and queue setting:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=new_task_id, durable=True, auto_delete=True)
```

Basically, consumer and producer are like this:

consumer:

```
def task(task_id):
    def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
        if body != "quit":
            print(body)
        else:
            print(body)
            channel.stop_consuming(task_id)

    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=task_id, no_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()
    print("finish")
    return "finish"
```

producer:

```
proc = Popen(['app/sample.sh'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
while proc.returncode is None:  # running
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        channel.basic_publish(
            exchange='',
            routing_key=self.request.id,
            body=line
        )
    else:
        channel.basic_publish(
            exchange='',
            routing_key=self.request.id,
            body="quit"
        )
        break
```

consumer `task` gave me output:

```
# ... output from sample.sh, as expected

quit
�}q(UstatusqUSUCCESSqU  tracebackqNUresultqNUtask_idqU
1419350416qUchildrenq]u.
```

However, `"finish"` didn't get printed, so I'm guessing it's because `channel.stop_consuming(task_id)` didn't stop consuming. If so, what is the correct way to do? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that stop_consuming gets called?

Comment: @eandersson Yes I'm sure.

Comment: Ok. Are you sure you are passing the correct ID to stop_consuming? Try simply using ```channel.stop_consuming()```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems to be caused by the fact that internally, `start_consuming` calls `self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)`. This `time_limit=None` makes it hang.

I managed to workaround this problem by replacing the call to `channel.start_consuming()` with its implemenation, hacked:

```
while channel._consumer_infos:
    channel.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=1) # 1 second
```

Comment: I don't have the condition to testify your answer now, anyway, I'll accept it.

Comment: shx2, you're right I think. At least, that's what I also understood by looking at the source. And it also seems to fix the problem. I'll open a ticket.

Comment: Even with this code, polling did not stop!

Answer (score 2):

I have a class defined with member variables of channel and connection. These are initialized by a seperate thread. The consumer of MyClient Class uses the close() method and the the connection and consumer is stopped!

```
class MyClient:

    def __init__(self, unique_client_code):
        self.Channel = None
        self.Conn: pika.BlockingConnection = None  
        self.ClientThread = self.init_client_driver()

    def _close_callback(self):
        self.Channel.stop_consuming()
        self.Channel.close()
        self.Conn.close()
    def _client_driver_thread(self, tmout=None):
        print("Starting Driver Thread...")
        self.Conn = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost"))
        self.Channel = self.Conn.channel()

    def init_client_driver(self, tmout=None):
        kwargs = {'tmout': tmout}
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._client_driver_thread, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        return t

    def close(self):
        self.Conn.add_callback_threadsafe(self._close_callback)
        self.ClientThread.join()
```