# Pika channel.stop_consuming doesn't stop start_consuming loop

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have this piece of code, basically it run *channel.start_consuming()*.
I want it to stop after a while.

I think that *channel.stop_consuming()* is the right method:

```
def stop_consuming(self, consumer_tag=None):
    """ Cancels all consumers, signalling the `start_consuming` loop to
    exit.
```

But it doesn't work: start_consuming() never ends (execution doesn't exit from this call, "end" is never printed).

import unittest
import pika
import threading
import time

```
_url = "amqp://user:password@xxx.rabbitserver.com/aaa"

class Consumer_test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_startConsuming(self):

        def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
            print("callback")
            print(body)

        def connectionTimeoutCallback():
            print("connecionClosedCallback")

        def _closeChannel(channel_):
            print("_closeChannel")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("close")
            if channel_.is_open:
                channel_.stop_consuming()
                print("stop_cosuming")
            else:
                print("channel is closed")
            #channel_.close()

        params = pika.URLParameters(_url)
        params.socket_timeout = 5
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
        #connection.add_timeout(2, connectionTimeoutCallback)
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.basic_consume(callback,
                              queue='test',
                              no_ack=True)

        t = threading.Thread(target=_closeChannel, args=[channel])
        t.start()

        print("start_consuming")
        channel.start_consuming()  # start consuming (loop never ends)
        connection.close()
        print("end")
```

*connection.add_timeout* solve my problem, maybe call basic_cancel too, but I want to use the right method.

Thanks

Note:
I can't respond or add comment to this ([pika, stop_consuming does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624166/pika-stop-consuming-does-not-work)) due to my low reputation points.

Note 2:
I think that I'm not sharing channel or connection across threads (Pika doesn't support this) because I use "channel_" passed as parameter and not "channel" instance of the class (Am I wrong?).

Comment: This is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624166/pika-stop-consuming-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem; as `pika` is not thread safe. i.e. connections and channels can't be safely shared across threads.

So I used a separate connection to send a shutdown message; then stopped consuming the original channel from the `callback` function.